# Lost product image roles when save product by program

Tags: magento2, product, product-images

When I save Product in shell(foreach loop) like below, the product image roles will disappear!

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($data['product_id']);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

I google it and found it is a **official bug** and not fixed yet(include version 2.1, 2.2, 2.3). The official github issue link is [Product image roles randomly disappear](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10687). The codes below will lost all image roles too.

```
$store = $this->storeManager->getStore(0);
$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($store);
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($data['product_id'], true, $store->getId());
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

It seems as long as we use `$this->productRepository->save($product);`, it will lost product image roles.

How to **temporarily solve** the problem before the official fix the bug?

Comment: This code where we have to place @Key Shang? To make it working what I have to do?
I dont understand your explanations clearly. I have the same issue, all my product images are without role now. And I have more than 25K products. I only see now the placeholders. Code seems doing its job but where can I run this code?
Please give hand.
regards

Comment: @SavaşErdemÇalışkan Put the codes in your program which save product, if you donot have one, you could write a CLI command to load broken products and process the image roles by following my answer. Reference: [How to add CLI commands](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in github `$product->unsetData('media_gallery'); $this->productRepository->save($product);`, but it will [make a critical error on the catalog_product_view page](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10687#issuecomment-336917364).

After research the productRepository codes, I came up with two **temporary solution** by myself. The problem cost my several hours, hope the solution will help others too.

> After my test, the solutions work in version 2.2.3. Other version should work too.

### 1. If you did not lost your image roles yet

Save the product by productRepository like below:

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($data['product_id']);
...
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($product->getMediaGalleryEntries());
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

### 2. If you already lost your image roles

If you already lost your image roles just like me T^T, you have to assign the image roles to products by custom shell or controller.

After get the product ids you want, for each product write the codes like below

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($data['product_id']);
$mediaGalleryEntriesTemp = [];
$i = 1;
foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryEntries() as $item) {
    if ($i === 1) {
        $item->setTypes(['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']);
    }
    $mediaGalleryEntriesTemp[] = $item;
    $i++;
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($mediaGalleryEntriesTemp);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

> Notice: '**swatch_image**' role only available in simple product or
>   configurable child product, not **configurable parent** product.

---

If someone has better solution, your post is welcome :)

Or the official fix the bug, please let me know.